# Flex Mobile - Is there an event triggered after view contents are fully displayed on the screen

Tags: events, flex4.5, flex-mobile

I'm trying to build an image gallery with photos fetched through an API. The API only allows 1 photo to be fetched at a time.

I want to display a photo and when the use swipes left/right display the previous or next photo.

I'd like the user experience to be seamless/fast. In order to achieve this I was thinking of doing the following:-
When a photo is viewed in full screen, fetch the previous and next photo in the background. 
However, what event should I use so that the API call process does not cause any delay to the user.

So my question is, **is there an event that is triggered after the photo/contents of the view is displayed on the screen.**

That way , I can call the API in that event and pre-fetch the data.

If there's a different approach altogether I should take then please do suggest that too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you can take is slightly different that what you think. The viewActivate event I believe is the one that is fired off when the view is fully rendered and is ready to be pushed to the screen, but I believe that firing off your request will cause some chunky behavior in the transition which brings the view on to the screen. What you really want to do is add an event listener to the actual transition that brings the view onto the screen and when the transition completes you should then fire off your API request to get the additional pictures. A transition fires off a FlexEvent.TRANSITION_END event when a transition is completed. So attach your listener to that and it should do what you are looking for.